# Second derivative in AsciiMath

Tags: mathjax, asciimath

I'd like to express "the second derivative of f(x)" in AsciiMath.

In LaTeX, it's simply `f''(x)`:

[image: 2nd derivative in LaTeX]

The same in AsciiMath results in single quotes instead prime symbols:

[image: 2nd derivative in AsciiMath]

I can get a perfect first derivative in AsciiMath using `f^'(x)`

[image: 1st derivative in AsciiMath]

But the same approach doesn't work for second derivative: `f^('')(x)`:

[image]

Is there a syntax in AsciiMath that results in the same output as LaTeX, with prime symbols and not single quotes?

Comment: f^('')(x) looks good for me on asciimath.org. the tics are a little smaller than the single tic for a first derivative, but that could be due to the font.

Comment: Thanks @JulianCienfuegos but I'm hoping to find some syntax that yields two prime symbols just like in the top example which uses LaTeX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you point out, AsciiMath doesn't handle this situation very well.  The approaches suggested so far produce poor quality MathML, and while MathJax's output handles even this awkward MathML, native MathML rendered (like Firefox's) will produce poorer results.  Here is `f^'text()^'(x)` rendered by Firefox's native MathML:

[image: f''(x)]

This is badly rendered because the underlying MathML has two separate `<msup>` elements, and the bases for the two superscripts are not the same height:

```
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
  <mstyle displaystyle="true">
    <mrow>
      <msup>
        <mi>f</mi>
        <mo>&#x2032;</mo>
      </msup>
      <msup>
        <mrow>
          <mtext></mtext>
        </mrow>
        <mo>&#x2032;</mo>
      </msup>
    </mrow>
    <mrow>
      <mo>(</mo>
      <mi>x</mi>
      <mo>)</mo>
    </mrow>
  </mstyle>
</math>
```

One possible solution that produces better MathML is to use the double-prime unicode character, U+2033, as in `f^″(x)`, or if you are entering it in an HTML page, as `f^&#x2033;(x)`.  This is rendered by MathJax's HTML-CSS output as

[image: f''(x) by MathJax]

and as

[image: f''(x) by Firefox]

by Forefox's native MathML renderer.  Moreover, the MathML that AsciiMath produces for this input is more semantically meaningful:

```
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
  <mstyle displaystyle="true">
    <mrow>
      <msup>
        <mi>f</mi>
        <mo>&#x2033;</mo>
      </msup>
      <mrow>
        <mo>(</mo>
        <mi>x</mi>
        <mo>)</mo>
      </mrow>
    </mrow>
  </mstyle>
</math>
```

There is also a triple prime at U+2034 and a quadruple prime at U+2057, in case you need those as well.  It would be nice if AsciiMath could combine the two separate primes into U+2033 automatically, but it doesn't currently do that.

Comment: Excellent solution!  I appreciate you sharing your extended knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
`f^('')(x)` 
It yields the following

[image]

Comment: Thanks but I tried this too.  In fact, I put this exact example in my question as one which isn't good enough.  It uses smaller, raised single quotes.  I'm looking for prime symbols or something as close to the LaTeX output as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve it by inserting an empty text block and putting the second prime symbol onto that, like this: `f^'text()^'(x)`

[image: Second derivative in AsciiMath]

There is also a slightly shorter form using quotes for the text block: `f^'""^'(x)`